# PrimeNG split-button styles

Tags: angular, button, primeng, split-button

I want to have a button like below.

[image]

When I use the PrimeNG split-button this is what I get

[image]

How can I change that to the button like in the first image?
and I want to use it in a table

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use PrimeNG menu to do that:

```
<button type="button" pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-plus" (click)="menu.toggle($event)"></button>
<p-menu #menu [popup]="true" [model]="items"></p-menu>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-menu-demo-kpacx5?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: It cannot be implemented in a table with editable rows

Comment: Yes you can, see this new [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableedit-demo-jnhk3i?file=src/app/app.component.ts).